# Connecting with external systems | How to design the system

Tags: c#, wcf, architecture

I have a question on how I should configure my system which interfaces with external systems.

Here are the various parts, which I was thinking of putting together:

**Option1**

- I have 3 external services which brings in 3 different types of messages to the system.
- I have a WCF service which listens to all these external services, which converts the messages into a common format.
- I have a WPF UI which is connected with the WCF service using duplex tcp binding, and messages gets updated on the UI.
- The UI also sends any outgoing messages to the service which in turn sends it to the external services.

My question is, do you think this is a scalable, maintainable, cost effective way to architect the solution? Do you see any specific problems that could come in if I deploy this in an intranet scenario?

The other consideration I was giving was the following:

**Option 2**

- Have 3 windows services which connects to the external services.
- Each service churns out the messages into a canonical format and puts it on a message bus on a specific topic.
- Have a WCF service which listens to the topics on the message bus for the new messages.
- Use a duplex binding to update the client with any incoming messages.
- Client sends the outgoing messages to the WCF service, which in turn drops it on to a specific topic listened by the windows services, which sends them to the external systems.

I'm bit confused here, could you please help me out with which one would be a better approach, and if you could, please point me to any links which discusses these scenarios?

Volume of data exchange is 400 messages every 5 minutes, divided across the external systems.

I'm sure lot of you might have faced this situation, so if you have a better approach to this please let me know.

Thanks,
-Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I certainly think your option 2 is correct when dealing with 3 similar but different message formats. This implements two integration patterns, the [adapter](http://www.eaipatterns.com/ChannelAdapter.html) and the [canonical message](http://www.eaipatterns.com/CanonicalDataModel.html).

However, I think using the same "adapter" services as conduits for messages travelling in the opposite direction would be a mistake. It would be better to abstract the response channel out of the request processing pipeline.

You could implement a distributor (or [router](http://www.eaipatterns.com/MessageRouter.html)) pattern to handle the routing of response messages back to the request source.